# Azure Key Vault - for each system identity on virtual machines created by a count

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I tried to create an Azure Key Vault access policy for multiple object_id. Theeses object_id are system identity from multiple virtuals machines created with the fonction 'count'.

I tried this :

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "terra_kva_pol_arr" {
  for_each = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.terra_vma_arr[*].identity[*].principal_id

  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.terra_kva[0].id
  tenant_id    = var.tenant_id
  object_id    = each.value

  secret_permissions = [
    "Get",
  ]
}
```

But I have this error :

```
│ Error: Invalid for_each argument
│
│   on key_vault.tf line 30, in resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "terra_kva_pol_arr":
│   30:   for_each = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.terra_vma_arr[*].identity[*].principal_id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.terra_vma_arr is tuple with 1 element
│
│ The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: the "for_each" argument must be a map, or set of strings, and you have provided a value of type tuple.
```

I think I need a more complex for_each but I am not an expert in this.

Thank you.

Comment: Sadly your question is unclear. What exactly is the issue? Did you try to write any code to solve your problem? Where is the code? What errors do you get?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the post. I think, it's more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep using `for_each` you can do:

```
for_each = toset(flatten(azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.terra_vma_arr[*].identity[*].principal_id))
```